# Does the phrase “a dragging experience” make any sense?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases, phrase-choice, pun

I am trying to come up with a pun for a specific situation.

> In a playground, there is a kid sitting down at the edge of a
> merry-go-round with his legs sticking out touching the ground. While
> it spins the legs are getting dragged over the ground. The kid looks
> at his legs quite unimpressed because the whole experience of having
> his legs dragged is rather dull.

So my pun for this was: “It was a dragging experience”. The literal meaning would be the legs getting dragged. Figuratively it would mean that the experience is boring and not fun.

Does the pun make sense? I am unsure because “drag” is usually used in the form of the phrase: “what a drag”.

Comment: It does make sense, but is not common usage. Perhaps, "It was a real drag," might get the idea across. You can add, "pretty rough," or "I scraped through," if his footwear was abraded.

Comment: Pippik (above) is correct; the pun only works with *drag* as a noun. Your idea is too literal, and thus is no longer a pun. *It was a drag* is colorful, but so common nowadays that it just sounds informal, and *It (the experience) dragged on" is a plain, descriptive way to say the event was dull. To describe the experience as a "dragging" one is odd - the listener will wonder why you have altered the idiom.  As the above says, to be humorous, just say "It was a drag."  It is funny enough to use, but only because it is quick. The humor is that it is a literal example of the idiom.

Answer (score 1):

For it to be a pun, it needs to have a duality of meaning. As you point out, the word "drag" has multiple meanings, but using the word alone in the same context will not make people think you are making a pun. You need to use the word out of context in a recognisable idiom so that people make the link between the two uses of the word.

There are more elegant puns I could give as examples, but for instantly recognisable one-liners, look no further than the movies of Arnold Schwarzenegger. He'd pin someone to a wall and say "stick around" (which idiomatically means "wait"), push someone off a cliff and say "I had to drop him off" (meaning leave someone somewhere) or cut someone in half and say "he had to split" (meaning leave in a hurry). In all these examples, the idiomatic phrase is used out of context.

For your example to be a pun, you'd need to say "it was a drag" or "a real drag", which idiomatically mean something was tiring or boring.